# How to limit grpc bandwidth using nginx

Tags: nginx, grpc, pyarrow

I'm using following nginx config. `limit_rate`. but it does not work

```
server {
    listen 31000 http2;
    server_name grpc.aeins-test.com;

    location ^~ /arrow.flight.protocol.FlightService {
        limit_rate 1k;
        grpc_set_header Host $host;
        grpc_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        grpc_pass_header X-Accel-Limit-Rate;
        grpc_socket_keepalive on;
        grpc_pass grpc://grpcserver;
    }
}
```